# How to introduce conjunctions into a conditional statements so as to get the CNF and DNF?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I have the following conditional statement: ((p → q) → p) → p

Knowing that CNF is a conjunction of disjunctions (and that DNF is a disjunction of conjunctions), we will obviously have to introduce conjunctions and disjunctions.

Knowing that p → q can be alternatively expressed as ¬p ∨ q, it seems (to me) fairly easy how we could convert all of these conditionals into disjunctions.

However, I'm completely clueless as to how to introduce *con*junctions. How could we do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oops! Yes, how careless of me -- I meant "∨". It's been edited now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.   You are thinking of Implication Equivalence.   There is also Implication's Negation Equivalence.

$$\begin{align}\text{I.E.}~&&\phi\to\psi~~\iff \lnot \phi\vee\psi\tag{note: disjunction}\\\text{I.N.E.}~&&\lnot(\phi\to\psi)\iff\phi\land\lnot\psi\tag{note: conjunction}\end{align}$$

So using these, step by step::$$\begin{align}1.&&((p\to q)\to p)\to p\tag{Premise}\\2.&&\lnot((p\to q)\to p)\lor p\tag{by I.E. on 1}\\3.&&((p\to q)\land\lnot p)\lor p\tag{by I.N.E on 2}\\4.&&((\lnot p\lor q)\land\lnot p)\lor p\tag{by I.E. on 3}\end{align}$$

Then we may distribute one way, aiming for a DNF::

$$\begin{align}5.&&(\lnot p\land\lnot p)\lor (q\land\lnot p)\lor p\tag{Distribute $\land/\lor$ on 4}\end{align}$$

Or we may distribute the other way, aiming for a CNF::

$$\begin{align}6.&&(\lnot p\lor q\lor p)\land(\lnot p\lor p)\tag{Distribute $\lor/\land$ on 4}\end{align}$$

Of course, *neither of these* are their final form.   You will *still* need to reduce them by using a few other Equivalence Rules.